# Как определить, есть ли хотя бы одно значение меньше 10

Tags: python

Необходим скрипт для проверки значений списка. Не могу сообразить как
прописать, что если любое из значений меньше 10, то в консоль
выводится однократное Ок.

```
a=[1.2, 2.4, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, 7.2]
for i in range(len(a)):

    if  a[0]>20 or a[i]>10 :
        print('No')
        break
    elif a[i]<10:
        continue
        print('Ok')
```

Comment: А почему `continue` раньше вызываете?

Comment: предполагал, что continue дойдет до конца и будет вызов print

Comment: Ну, это не так :)

Comment: А зачем проверка больше 20 в первом элементе? Если у Вас в условии задачи его нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
a=[1.2, 2.4, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, 7.2]
for i in range(len(a)):

    if  a[0]>20 or a[i]>10 :
        print('No')
        break

if min(a)<10:
    print('Ok')
```

Общая идея переделки - по максимуму использовать средства языка - они быстрее. Цикл - только там, где нужно. Если можно список сразу обработать - так и делаем.

Comment: @insolor, Cпасибо, верно. Заметил сам и исправил. Почему-то copy-paste не срабатывает, как нужно. Делаю пропуск строки , потом 8 символов отступ, а копируется криво.

Comment: Не нужно 8 символов, нужно 4, добавляется автоматически выделением кода и нажатием Ctrl-K. Ну и проще вставить как есть, добавить выше и ниже кода тройной косой апостроф ```

Comment: @insolor, Спасибо!

Comment: @leonardik, не забудьте выбрать потом один из двух ответов в качестве принятого ответа, чтобы он был полезнее для сообщества:-)

Answer (score 5):

Решается в одну строку с помощью генератора и `next()`, получающей первый результат.

Если нашли что-то больше 10, то значит No, иначе Ok

```
a = [1.2, 2.4, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, 7.2]
print('No' if next((e for e in a if e > 10), None) else 'Ok')
# Ok
a = [1.2, 20.4, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, 7.2]
print('No' if next((e for e in a if e > 10), None) else 'Ok')
# No
```

Comment: Решается в одну строку гораздо красивее)

Comment: Ха, точно))) Голова решето. Хотя мне больше такой вариант нравится `print('No' if next((e for e in a if e > 10), None) else 'Ok')`. Даже ответ поправил)))

Comment: Это же гораздо менее понятно, чем `any(...)` :)

Comment: У меня ощущение, что `any` сначала собирает список, а потом уже проверяет. Так по идее быстрее должно быть.

Comment: @AndyPavlov, any идет до первого истинного значения в итераторе.

Answer (score 5):

Только да: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1HBViHaUM9IR8FIzwREmOsoGOsZgAhDHQVzPaNYrsw0hcS8So0KBRsFQwOFtPwihQqFzDyFRE0rhYKizLwSDXX/bHXN//8B)

```
a = [1.2, 2.4, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, 7.2]
if any(x < 10 for x in a): print('Ok')
```

Да или нет: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##FcQ9CoAgAAbQvVN8mwoi/gROdYT2iAYHJSFUrEFPb/SGV/p75WTGcFhwKKE5tJj/LIcR8k9xWKHPqdSYXkp2/xDEAJc6bVihJEKuaIgJjsHfjwfZMmFjfA)

```
a = [1.2, 2.4, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, 7.2]
print('Yes' if any(x > 10 for x in a) else 'No')
```

Comment: Вот вопрос. `any()` в данном случае проходит весь список или до первого `False`, как генератор?

Comment: @AndyPavlov, насколько я понимаю, т. е. квадратных скобок нет, то предполагаются круглые, т. е. генератор, а значит any перебирает до первого True. Но поскольку на питоне не пишу, могу и ошибаться.

Comment: @AndyPavlov, до первого True - вот [проверка](https://tio.run/##RYuxCoAgGAb3/ym@UcEl3QKfJBqEtIT4FTGwpzejoe047vJdj8Sm980HnGnn4qtociYgl8gvDxzyKoxG5GCxTApawaz0JY5v8a@wFhohFTREhpOy9wc): ```def lognret(x):
  print(x)
  return x

a = [1, 2, 3]
print(any(lognret(x) == 2 for x in a))``` - тройка не выводится.

Answer (score 1):

> такой еще вариант сработал

```
a=[1.2, 2.4, 2.7, 5.0, 3.1, 7.2]
for i in range(len(a)):

    if  a[0]>20 or a[i]>10 :
        print('No')
        break
else:
    print('Ok')
```

Comment: я просто формально отработал, что просили. А то потом первая проверка уйдет - и привет.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]